# Jquery mobile function not working == page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, refresh, text-to-speech

Ok this thing is driving me crazy. I have a simple project in which I use this [mobile bootstrap](https://github.com/commadelimited/jQuery-Mobile-Bootstrap-Theme) theme and this [text-to-speech](http://www.masswerk.at/mespeak/) library

Whenever there's an error in my function, the page just refreshes itself. In this way I can never read any output from the console.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {    
        $('#input-submit').click(function() {
            var text = $('#input-box').val();
            console.log(text);
            for (var i = 0;i < text.length; i++){
                alert('test');
                meSpeak.speak(text.charAt(i));
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want my app to spell out loud whatever the user fills in. The function works correctly until the `meSpeak.speak(text.charAt(i));` line. When I type in a 3 character word I get 3 alerts, and then the page just refreshes itself.

Why does it refresh when there's something not working? I want to read the output from the console without using alerts. Also, does anyone know why I can't use `meSpeak.speak(text.charAt(i));` like this?

Comment: You're not preventing the submit button from "submitting" the page, and as you've most likely set no destination, it's submitting to the same location, causing a page refresh.

Comment: How would I prevent it from "submitting" then? There's no real 'link' attribute in the button, and e.preventDefault is not working for me

Comment: Try returning `false`. That usually seems to work for canceling form submits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not preventing the submit button from "submitting" the page, and as you've most likely set no destination, it's submitting to the same location, causing a page refresh.

Preventing the click event can be done in *jQuery* by `return`ing `false` at the end of the *function*

```
$('#input-submit').click(function () {
    /* etc */
    return false;
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3j7Uv/) to play with